# Word wrapping text inside div

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

How to make span word-wrapped inside a div

[image: not wrapped]

The code:

```
<div class="col-xs-6 choice btn btn-default" >
  <span class="pull-left">(Kepala) Bagian Purchasing (tidak ada di SK? aslinya under WR2) [Purchasing]</span> <!-- this one needs to be wrapped -->
  <span class="pull-right">
    <span class="label label-primary" title="total">1</span>
  </span>
</div>
```

I need a css rule that able to break long text inside that `div.choice`

Comment: can you put this in a jsfiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following in your css

```
div.choice {
  white-space:normal !important;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Comment: no, it doesn't work, the span still goes across the div.

Comment: i've edited your answer, adding one more `white-space:normal !important` and removing the first span solves the problem

Comment: Setting `white-space` apparently overrides some setting elsewhere, hence solves the problem. Setting `word-wrap: break` is completely different and causes wo rds to be br oken a ribitrari ly, which is not acceptable in any language written with Latin letters.